# When clicking cluster, how to show Infowindow which has markers's values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have been trying to use google map with angularJS.

I have learned how to use it through https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/.

Everything goes well.

For each marker, I can show InfoWindow which has an element information of myList.

But I have got stuck in InfoWindow with cluster.

When cluster is clicked, I want to show the information list of markers in cluster.
Even I can't show simple InforWindow when clicking the cluster.

Below sources are my code.
Please tell me if it is not enough to solve my problem.

Please tell me what is wrong and how to solve this.
Have a nice day.

```
* javascript
$scope.map.map = { 
    center: { latitude: $scope.map.myList[0].lat, longitude: $scope.map.myList[0].lng }, 
    zoom: 17,
    events : {
        tilesloaded: function (map) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
                    var lat = $scope.map.myList[$scope.map.markerPosition-1].lat;
                    var lng = $scope.map.myList[$scope.map.markerPosition-1].lng;
                    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    map.setCenter(center);
                });
            });
        }
    },

    markersEvents: {
        click: function(marker, eventName, model) {

            model.show = !model.show;
            return;
        }
    },
    clusterOptions : { // options of cluster
        gridSize: 40,
        ignoreHidden: true,
        zoomOnClick : false,
        averageCenter : true,
        styles: [
                 {
                     height: 53,
                     url: "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m3.png",
                     width: 53,
                     textColor : 'white'
                 }
         ]
    },
    clusterEvent: { // when cluster's clicked 
        click: function(map, markers) {

            var contentString = 'ABCD';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
            });

            infowindow.open(map, markers);
            return;
        }
    }
};
$scope.map.options = {
    streetViewControl : false
};
$scope.map.markers = [];





* html
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.map.center' zoom="map.map.zoom" options="map.options" events="map.map.events">
<ui-gmap-markers models="map.markers" coords="'self'" icon="a" events="map.map.markersEvents" options="'options'"
        doCluster="true" clusterOptions="map.map.clusterOptions" clusterEvents="map.map.clusterEvent">
        <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
            <div ng-non-bindable>{{id}}</div>
        </ui-gmap-windows> 
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer myself.

```
var infoWindowOptions = {
        content: "asdfasdf"
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
infowindow.open(map.map_, *marker*);
```